# Is there a name for the matrix constructed in this way. Does it have any other interested properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Recently I participated in a competition, where I was given two vectors $X$ and $Y$. A matrix is constructed from this two vectors in such a way that

$$M_{i,j} = \frac{1}{x_i + y_j}$$

The task was to find a determinant of this matrix (which I successfully done).

---

My question is whether this matrix has a specific name and may be some other (except of determinant) interested properties or applications? By specific name I mean [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices).

Comment: From the list you linked, it could be a cauchy matrix.

Comment: @DanielV you are right, this is it.

Comment: I'll write it as an answer so the question can be marked as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequences do not have any repeated values, then it is a [Cauchy Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).